# IOS [__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, tableview

I am trying to create a dynamic slide menu like facebook.

I have to get some data from a json request. and display this data in one of the sections of the slide table view.
I'm new in objective-c, I also tried with NSMutableArrays and I had an error. 
In other table views I do the same but  without sections. only one MutableArray and I can show the table.

I do something like this:

```
-(void) requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:(NSDictionary *)parsedObject{


  NSArray  *projectsObjectArray = [parsedObject objectForKey:@"projects"];

    [self createMainNavigationController];
    self.section1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Profile", @"Notifications", @"Exit", nil];
    self.section2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Main", nil];


    for (NSDictionary *projectObject in projectsObjectArray)
    {
        Project *newProject = [[Project alloc] init];

        newProject.title= [projectObject objectForKey:@"title"];

        self.section3 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:newProject.title];
    }

    self.menu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.section1, self.section2, self.section3, nil];
    [menuTableView reloadData];
}
```

I am having this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

Comment: Please `NSLog(@"Val : %@",newProject.title);`. What is the output ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is because

```
newProject.title= [projectObject objectForKey:@"title"];
```

is nil, and you are trying to add it to the array.  Check to see what that value is by logging it

```
NSLog(@"%@", [projectObject objectForKey:@"title"]);
```